# how do i make responsive image in slider

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive

In mobile view the background image is not fit and all the right part is not shown

```css
.slick-slide{
  background-image: url(https://i09/slider-bg-1.webp);
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 1;
     float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slick-track">
<div class="slick-slide">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **background-size: 100%** or **background-size : cover** in css. This should help in fitting the background image to the main container. Any of the above options will work based on your requirement.

```css
.slick-slide{
  background-image: url(https://i09/slider-bg-1.webp);
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 1;
     float: left;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 100%; //or //background-size : cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="slick-track">
<div class="slick-slide">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: well, when i do that it repeat it self vertically , when i put background-repeat: norepeat, it doesn't fill the screen vertically

Comment: background-repeat : no-repeat , background-size : cover and background-position: center center - Please add these 3 options and try